# What are the use cases for having a function return by const value for non-builtin type?

Tags: c++, const-correctness

Recently I have read that it makes sense when returning by value from a function to qualify the return type const for non-builtin types, e.g.:

```
const Result operation() {
    //..do something..
    return Result(..);
}
```

I am struggling to understand the benefits of this, once the object has been returned surely it's the callers choice to decide if the returned object should be const?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Basically, there's a slight language problem here.

```
std::string func() {
    return "hai";
}

func().push_back('c'); // Perfectly valid, yet non-sensical
```

Returning const rvalues is an attempt to prevent such behaviour. However, in reality, it does way more harm than good, because now that rvalue references are here, you're just going to prevent move semantics, which sucks, and the above behaviour will probably be prevented by the judicious use of rvalue and lvalue `*this` overloading. Plus, you'd have to be a bit of a moron to do this anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that marking the rvalue as const prevents move semantics? My version of clang lets a custom move constructor get called with a const rvalue (though it doesn't let a non-const rvalue reference get bound to it, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on).

Comment: @John Calsbeek: How can you move from a const rvalue? You can't modify it- because it's const.

Comment: @John: But can your const move constructor really perform the move? E.g. suppose your class had a raw pointer that needed to be freed. In the move constructor, you copy the pointer, but you also have to set the copy in the RHS object to NULL so it doesn't get double-deleted. But if it's a const rvalue, you can't modify it...

Comment: It is nonsensical for `void` methods. For methods that return something it can make perfect sense. For example, if `string::push_back` returned a reference to the string itself, you'd be able to do `string s = func().push_back('c');` (for one example).

Comment: I managed to get my version of clang to, via a move constructor, bind a `const T` to a `T&&`, and mutate it through the rvalue reference. I'm just trying to figure out if that's a bug in clang or not. (I can't think of a "truly const" rvalue, besides one that was casted from a lvalue that was declared as const.)

Comment: @John: const object being bound to non-const reference... rvalue or not, that violates const correctness and should not be allowed. My guess is it's a bug

Comment: It's how they used to be, but the spec was since changed.

Comment: @John: if you activate the warnings on CLang, does not it say that the top level qualifiers of the return type are ignored, ie that it treats `T volatile * const` as `T volatile *` ?

Comment: For newer classes, I would recommend making `push_back()` a `&`-qualified method, like `void push_back() &;`. It'll prohibit calling it on temporary values. I think it's better option, because "`push_back` should not be called on a temporary" is really a property of `push_back`, not `func()`. It, however, still allows nonsense like `func() = "foo"`.

Answer (score 24):

It is occasionally useful. See this example:

```
class I
{
public:
    I(int i)                   : value(i) {}
    void set(int i)            { value = i; }
    I operator+(const I& rhs)  { return I(value + rhs.value); }
    I& operator=(const I& rhs) { value = rhs.value; return *this; }

private:
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    I a(2), b(3);
    (a + b) = 2; // ???
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the value returned by `operator+` would normally be considered a temporary. But it's clearly being modified. That's not exactly desired.

If you declare the return type of `operator+` as `const I`, this will fail to compile.

Comment: Item 3 from the "Effective C++"

Answer (score 11):

There is no benefit when returning by value. It doesn't make sense.

The only difference is that it prevents people from using it as an lvalue:

```
class Foo
{
    void bar();
};

const Foo foo();

int main()
{
    foo().bar(); // Invalid
}
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect. It doesn't prevent people from using it as an lvalue at all. It prevents people from using it as a non-const object. These are two completely different things.

Comment: class Foo
{
public:
    void bar() {};
};
Foo foo() { return Foo();} ;

Answer (score 5):

Last year I've discovered another surprising usecase while working on a two-way C++-to-JavaScript bindings.

It requires a combination of following conditions:

- You have a copyable and movable class `Base`.
- You have a non-copyable non-movable class `Derived` deriving from `Base`.
- You really, really do not want an instance of `Base` inside `Derived` to be movable as well.
- You, however, really want slicing to work for whatever reason.
- All classes are actually templates and you want to use template type deduction, so you cannot really use `Derived::operator const Base&()` or similar tricks instead of public inheritance.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

// Simple class which can be copied and moved.
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    std::string data;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
    // Complex class which derives from Base<T> so that type deduction works
    // in function calls below. This class also wants to be non-copyable
    // and non-movable, so we disable copy and move.
    Derived() : Base<T>{"Hello World"} {}
    ~Derived() {
        // As no move is permitted, `data` should be left untouched, right?
        assert(this->data == "Hello World");
    }
    Derived(const Derived&) = delete;
    Derived(Derived&&) = delete;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = delete;
    Derived& operator=(Derived&&) = delete;
};

// assertion fails when the `const` below is commented, wow!
/*const*/ auto create_derived() { return Derived<int>{}; }

// Next two functions hold reference to Base<T>/Derived<T>, so there
// are definitely no copies or moves when they get `create_derived()`
// as a parameter. Temporary materializations only.
template<typename T>
void good_use_1(const Base<T> &) { std::cout << "good_use_1 runs" << std::endl; }

template<typename T>
void good_use_2(const Derived<T> &) { std::cout << "good_use_2 runs" << std::endl; }

// This function actually takes ownership of its argument. If the argument
// was a temporary Derived<T>(), move-slicing happens: Base<T>(Base<T>&&) is invoked,
// modifying Derived<T>::data.
template<typename T>
void oops_use(Base<T>) { std::cout << "bad_use runs" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    good_use_1(create_derived());
    good_use_2(create_derived());
    oops_use(create_derived());
}
```

The fact that I did not specify the type argument for `oops_use<>` means that the compiler should be able to deduce it from argument's type, hence the requirement that `Base<T>` is actually a real base of `Derived<T>`.

An implicit conversion should happen when calling `oops_use(Base<T>)`. For that, `create_derived()`'s result is materialized into a temporary `Derived<T>` value, which is then moved into `oops_use`'s argument by `Base<T>(Base<T>&&)` move constructor. Hence, the materialized temporary is now moved-from, and the assertion fails.

We cannot delete that move constructor, because it will make `Base<T>` non-movable. And we cannot really prevent `Base<T>&&` from binding to `Derived<T>&&` (unless we explicitly delete `Base<T>(Derived<T>&&)`, which should be done for all derived classes).

So, the only resolution without `Base` modification here is to make `create_derived()` return `const Derived<T>`, so that `oops_use`'s argument's constructor cannot move from the materialized temporary.

I like this example because not only it compiles both with and without `const` without any undefined behaviour, it behaves differently with and without `const`, and the correct behavior actually happens with `const` only.

Comment: Of course, that initial set of requirements violates Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Also, a more robust approach here would be to modify `Base` so that it cannot move from non-movable derived classes by adding a templated SFINAEd copy constructor.