# const Class * const Function() What does the second const do?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference, constants

What does the second const do in the structure below? (it's just an example function).

I understand that the first const makes the function return a constant object. But I can't figure out what the const before the identifier does.

First I though that it returned a constant pointer to a constant object, but I'm still able to reassign the returned pointer, so I guess that isn't the case.

```
const SimpleClass * const Myfunction()
{
   SimpleClass * sc;
   return sc;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: It *does* return a constant pointer to a constant object. You can copy the *value* of that pointer to a non-const variable. (It's the same principle as `const int f() { return 0; } int main() { int x = f(); x = 1; }`.)

Comment: Want another *const*? Add it at the end of  the MyFunction() line. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const SimpleClass * const Myfunction()
{   
    return sc;
}

decltype(auto) p = Myfunction();
p = nullptr; // error due to the second const.
```

But the truth is that not many people uses decltype(auto), and your function will be normally called like:

```
const SimpleClass *p = Myfunction();
p = nullptr; // success, you are not required to specify the second const.

const auto* p = Myfunction();
p = nullptr; // success, again: we are not required to specify the second const.
```

And...

```
const SimpleClass * const p = Myfunction();
p = nullptr; // error

const auto* const p = Myfunction();
p = nullptr; // error
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Second `const` means that returned pointer is constant itself whereas first `const` means that memory is unmodifiable.

Returned pointer is temporary value (*rvalue*). That's why it doesn't matter whether it's `const` or not since it cannot be modified anyway: `Myfunction()++;` is wrong. One way to "feel" second `const` is to use `decltype(auto) p = Myfunction();` and try to modify `p` as [José](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866175/jos%C3%A9) pointed out.

You might be interested in [Purpose of returning by const value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value) and [What are the use cases for having a function return by const value for non-builtin type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299967/what-are-the-use-cases-for-having-a-function-return-by-const-value-for-non-built)