# Does removing const from a function return type break ABI?

Tags: c++, constants, abi

Assume I have a library that declares a function returning `const` type:

```
class Foo { ... };
const Foo makeFoo();
```

Now I want to remove `const` from `makeFoo()` return type (See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418387/const-cast-and-stdmove-to-remove-constness-from-non-reference?noredirect=1#comment62367815_37418387)). I can remove `const` both from the header and the cpp file, rebuild the library, and link my code to the new library. However, I also have old code that is dynamically linked to this library, and I want it to continue to work with the new version of the library.

So, first question, does removing `const` from return type break ABI?

Second question, the actual code is quite different: it is a template class that has a static member function and that is later explicitly instantiated:

```
// fooMaker.h
template<class Foo>
class FooMaker {
public:
    static const Foo make();
};

// fooMaker.cpp
template<class Foo>
const Foo FooMaker<Foo>::make() { ... }

template class FooMaker<Foo1>;
template class FooMaker<Foo2>;
```

Is it changing anything?

If that's important, I'm using g++ under linux.

Comment: Are you looking for a practical answer or a legal one standardwise?

Comment: Is there any difference between returning a `Foo` or a `const Foo`? What is the `const` adding/changing?

Comment: @ZunTzu, in fact I see two possible problems: name mangling and possible UB due to treatment of a non-const object as const (imagine I was _adding_ const instead of removing; then this will clearly lead to UB similarly to my previous question). For the former, I am more interested in a practical answer for g++/linux, as if g++ changes name mangling scheme, then this will not be the only problem. For the latter, I am more interested in a legal one answer, as it is not good to leave some UB or the like behind.

Comment: @Walter, see [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418387/const-cast-and-stdmove-to-remove-constness-from-non-reference?noredirect=1#comment62367815_37418387) (also linked in question body), and links there.

Comment: Since the return type is not part of the mangled function name, there is no effect on name mangling.

Comment: Practical answer : g++ name mangling apparently does not use the return type (see [here](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gcc/gxxint_15.html)).

Comment: Legal answer : last time I checked C++ had no standard ABI.

Comment: @Petr In that previous question of yours, you accepted the wrong answer: Vaugh Cato's answer works and, I think, is perfectly legal. If that is so, perhaps this question is superfluous?

Comment: On the legal side: If the definition differs from the declaration in this way you have an ODR violation. Practically I doubt it matters.

Comment: @Walter, in fact I was unsure which to accept. I accepted SergeyA'a because it explicitly mentions a _temporary_, and that was what I did not realize myself before asking a question, so that answer was indeed enlighting to me and allowed me to see clearly why it is UB. Vaugh Cato's answer seems correct, but we have decided that it's better to fix the library instead of workarounding in the user code; the library is in fact not completely out of my control, just developed by other people.

Answer (score 1):

The following [guidelines](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B) on what affects the ABI suggest that the answer is yes, it does break ABI compatibility:

> You cannot
>
> ...
>
> For existing functions of any type:
>
> - changing the
>   return type in any way

Since you are changing the return type from `const Foo` to `Foo` I would say this falls foul.

Comment: This answer is insufficient in this case. It is not obvious if the change is meaningful enough to affect ABI (returning a const type accomplishes nothing really).

Comment: That `guidelines` come from KDE community and it is more of a set of observations that guarantee mostly-safe coding. This means I dont take it as a valuable reference. For that, it would need to come from the compiler's creators/manuals/etc. I also understand ZunTzu's doubt. Removing `const/volatile` modifier "feels cosmetic", it shouldnt affect the structure/sizes/etc of anything. Although I can **imagine** a compiler that allocates space for return-values differently basing on constness, it would be .. strange, very strange.