# Why is it possible to modify a returned value when the return type is const?

Tags: c++, constants, return-value, return-type

I was under the impression that by declaring a return type `const`, you could prevent the data structure from being modified.  However, I tested this and I can modify the data structures.  Why is that?

For example, the following code prints `1 2 3 4 5 6` when compiled with `--std=c++11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
const set<int> f(void) {
    set<int> s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return s;
}
int main(void) {
    set<int> s = f();
    s.insert(6);

    for (auto elem: s) {
        cout << elem << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s` is a copy of the set that was returned by the function, and it's not declared `const`.

Comment: Const non-reference return types are not really useful.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299967/what-are-the-use-cases-for-having-a-function-return-by-const-value-for-non-built

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `s` is a different object which constructed from the returned value. It has nothing to do with the returned object, and it's a *non-const* object itself.

The `const` qualifier for the return value means you can't modify on it directly, like

```
f().insert(6); // fail
```

Comment: @M.M It seems won't prevent [NRVO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). "and which has the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification) as the return type of the function, ..." [live demo for test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RIwH6rw5w8D2qWm7)